# Do I need to specify body, html at the top of my CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have been using the following at the top of every page.

```
body, html {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    line-height: 1.15;
}
```

But my workmate tells me I don't need both `body` and `html`.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't, you can omit `html`. All visible and presentational content to be formatted and styled with css will (and should) be within the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

For the code above, you really don't need to style both `html` and `body`

**However**, some browsers apply `margin` and `padding` to one or the other, so it is a good practice to reset both

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

This helps especially if you are trying to place elements against the top/bottom of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with `margin`, `width` or `height` and perhaps `background` you may need to target both, but for general properties, you don't. The properties you list here are fine on just `body`.